# Ruby Shoes Hover element

Tags: ruby, hover, shoes

Hover element dosen't work. Where is problem? How fix it?

```
Shoes.app :width => 635, :height => 410 do
    background image "http://PATH_TO_IMAGE"
    a = stack :width => 360, :height => 200, :margin_left => 250, :margin_top => 200 do
        hover do
            a.clear { para "Some Text qwe qwe qwerty", :stroke => black }
        end
        leave do
            a.clear { background image "http://PATH_TO_IMAGE" }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in principle you cannot use `image` as the argument for `background`.

I also am not sure if that is effect you want to achieve but it shows what you did wrong:

```
Shoes.app :width => 635, :height => 410 do

  a = stack :width => 360, :height => 200  do
    image "http://PATH_TO_IMAGE"

    hover do
         a.clear {para "Some Text qwe qwe qwerty", :stroke => black }
    end

    leave do
        a.clear {  image "http://PATH_TO_IMAGE" }
    end

  end

end
```